# Como colocar os estados tirados do site do ibge em ordem alfabética?

Tags: javascript

```
 fetch("https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados")
    .then( res => res.json() )
    .then( states => {

    for( const state of states ) {
        ufSelect.innerHTML += `<option value="${state.sigla}">${state.sigla}</option>`
    }

        
    })
}

populateUFs()

function getCities(event) {
    const citySelect = document.querySelector("[name=city]")
    const stateInput = document.querySelector("[name=state]")
    
    const ufValue = event.target.value

    const indexOfSelectedState = event.target.selectedIndex
    stateInput.value = event.target.options[indexOfSelectedState].text

    const url = `https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados/${ufValue}/municipios`


    citySelect.innerHTML = "<option value>Selecione a cidade</option>"
    citySelect.disabled = true

    fetch(url)
    .then( res => res.json() )
    .then( cities => {
        
    for( const city of cities ) {
        citySelect.innerHTML += `<option value="${city.nome}">${city.nome}</option>`
    }

    citySelect.disabled = false
        
    })

}


document
   .querySelector("select[name=uf]")
    .addEventListener("change", getCities)
```

Comment: Inseriu na pergunta muito código sem necessidade, bastaria mostrar o formato que está recebendo os estados da Api e o que tentou fazer para ordenar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para organizar um determinado *array*, o *JavaScript* disponibiliza uma função chamada `sort`.

De acordo com a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), você pode passar uma função para ter critérios personalizados. Esta função deve retornar um dos valores possíveis, que são: *-1*, *0* ou *1*.

**Exemplo:**

```
arr.sort((a, b) => a > b ? 1 : -1)
```

- Se *a* for menor que *b*, deve retornar *-1*
- Se *a* for maior que *b*, deve retornar *1*
- Se *a* for igual a *b*, deve retornar *0*

```js
const ufSelect = document.querySelector('#ufSelect');

fetch("https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados")
    .then( res => res.json() )
    .then( res => {
      return res.sort((a, b) => a.sigla > b.sigla ? 1 : -1)
    })
    .then( states => {
      for( const state of states ) {
          ufSelect.innerHTML += `<option value="${state.sigla}">${state.sigla}</option>`
      }
    })
```

```html
<select id="ufSelect" name="state"></select>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado meu amigo! Deu certinho aqui.